# How to check if one field is less than another in a Django form?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to check if the start time is less than the end time. If I did not want to raise a error.

My code looks like this:

```
class TimeOpeningHoursForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BusinessOpeningHours
        fields = ('mon_st', 'mon_end', ...)
        widgets = {
            'mon_st': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'mon_end': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            ...
        }

    def compare_mon(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        st = cleaned_data['mon_st']
        end = cleaned_data['mon_end']
        if st > end :
             raise forms.ValidationError("The start time must be less than the end time.")
        else:
              return cleaned_data
```

My validation code works as if it weren't there at all. Does not raise errors or verify correctness. In the view, of course, I check form via the `is_valid` method.

Comment: Your code shows that you've defined a method. Have you called that method somewhere? If not, it won't run.

Answer (score 1):

Django will not automatically run this method. You can override the [**`.clean()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) which is automatically called to validate fields that depend on each other:

```
class TimeOpeningHoursForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BusinessOpeningHours
        fields = ('mon_st', 'mon_end')
        widgets = {
            'mon_st': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'mon_end': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        st = cleaned_data['mon_st']
        end = cleaned_data['mon_end']
        if st > end :
             raise forms.ValidationError('The start time must be less than the end time.')
        return cleaned_data
```